# line 11: Mismatched input 'stopValue' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

Sorry I am new to coding. can anyone tell me why I am getting the error in subject? I dont see any errors with the indentation? Is this what this error means?

```
strategy("Reailing Stop", overlay = true)
if close> ta.sma(close, 50)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

// Trailing stop
Trailperc = 0.2
price_stop = 0.0

If  (strategy.position_size>0)
    stopValue = close*(1-Trailperc)
    price_stop := math.max(stopValue, price_stop[1] )
else
    price_stop := 0
if (strategy.position_size>0)
    strategy.exit(id= "Stop Loss", stop= price_stop  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a tabulation alignement issue: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Style_guide.html#vertical-alignment

Also you wrote

```
If  (strategy.position_size>0)
```

should be instead if with a low caps i

```
if  (strategy.position_size>0)
```